# Own service - no service for type has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, hangfire

I would like to use Hangfire in my ASP.NET Core app, bu I have got error message:

> No service for type has been registered

Here's my code:
Service:

```
public class MyService: IMyService
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public MyService(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // some code
}

public interface IMyService
{
      //some code
}
```

In Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
    // another services
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>().MyMethod(), Cron.Minutely);
}
```

Do you have any idea why service is not registered?

Comment: Is `IRssService` supposed to be the same as `IMyService` here?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, it the same. My mistake. I've already fixed it.

Comment: the problem is most likely the same as in this question, MyContext is registered as scoped or not registered at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369054/usermanager-dbcontext-already-disposed-in-middleware/39369908#39369908

Comment: Can't you use the proper Hangfire method for this? Something like this: `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IMyService>(s => s.MyMethod(), Cron.Minutely);`

Comment: @DavidG Yes, it works. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hangfire hooks into the dependency injection already in place so you don't need to use `serviceProvider.GetService` to get your object. Instead use the appropriate Hangfire function to let it resolve the dependency:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IMyService>(s => s.MyMethod(), Cron.Minutely);
```

Comment: this also worked for BackgroundJob.Enqueue `BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IMyService>(ms => ms.MyMethod());`